# Return true if a object is set to undefined in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I check if any object in an array of object is set to undefined.

How can I check if the 'author' is set to undefined?

```
const state = {
  sortBook: [
    { title: 'asc' },
    { author: undefined }
  ]
};
```

The main thing is that this array changes dynamically. So as the user set the data it could be:

```
const state = {
  sortBook: [
    { title: 'asc' },
    { editionYear: undefined }
  ]
}
```

So I need a way to iterate and check for undefined even though the object keys changes dynamically.

Comment: Does every object always have a single key-value pair?

Comment: yes, only one value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your update, you would just [iterate over the state object's entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with the same function. This would be the change:

```
function undefinedInState(state) {
  return Object.entries(state).map(([key, value]) => {
    return value.some(obj => Object.values(obj).some(v => v === undefined))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on both the outer array and the array returned from  [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). It's basically asking if `some` of the `values` in `some` of the objects in the array equal `undefined`.

This will check if any key in any of the objects equals `undefined`.

```js
const state = {sortBook : [
    {title: 'asc'},
    {author: undefined}
    ]};

const state2 = {sortBook: [
    {title: 'asc'},
    {author: 'Thucydides'}
    ]};
    
const state3 = {sortBook: [
    {title: 'asc'},
    {author: 'Alfred Thayer Mahan', someOtherKey: undefined}
    ]};


function undefed(arr) {
  return arr.some(obj => Object.values(obj).some(v => v === undefined))
}

console.log(undefed(state.sortBook))
console.log(undefed(state2.sortBook))
console.log(undefed(state3.sortBook)) // more than one key, but one is undefined
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. But let's say this array of objects is stored inside an object. Is that a way to use this function on it? Just realize I had to do this inside a state call... I'll edit my code

Comment: @asotos just pass in the array with `undefed(state.sortBook)` - I updated the answer.